# How to Layout Contents of Window when Resizing window width?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick

> Suppose I have a Grid, shows 4X4(4 rows and 4 columns), when I reduce
>   the width by half, It should layout as 2X8. I search in Google, and I
>   god some idea that, it can be achieve through calls of JavaScript to
>   change dynamically, but I have unable to get the window size after
>   re-size.

```
    import QtQuick 2.2

    Grid{
        id:root
        property int rootWidth:400//Created type to change using javascript
        property int rootHeight:400//Created type to change using javascript
        width:rootWidth
        height:rootHeight

        property int myRows: 4//Initially 4X4
        property int myColumns: 4
        rows: myRows
        columns: myColumns
        onWidthChanged:{ widthChange()}//Executed javascript, when width changes.
        Repeater{
            model:16
            //Fixed Rectangle.
            Rectangle{radius:36;width:100;height:100;color:"blue"}

        }
        function widthChange(){
            //It seems, this condition failes, How to get the width of the
            //window, after resizing the window?
            if( root.width > 200 & root.width <400 )
            {
            //When width is less than 400 and greater than 200, set Grid as 2X4.
            root.myColumns = 2;
            root.myRows = 8;
            root.rootWidth=200;
                root.rootHeight= 800;
            }
        }
    }
```

**What I am try to achieve is, I need to fit the content( Fixed Rectangles ) in Grid/or any with scroll-bar according to device width.** Can anyone help at least giving some hinds So i can work on this?, Appreciate if you know any alternative ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the question I've assumed that you also need the `ScrollBar`s, hence I've added the `ScrollView`. Even if we remove the latter, the general approach still applies.

The keypoint is in dynamically recalculate the number of necessary/available rows and colums. Then we can exploit QML binding and directly set the expressions to the `rows` and `columns` properties so that, when size changes, the values change accordingly. The resulting code is highlighted in the example below with `1)` and `2)`.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window{
    id: root
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible:  true

    ScrollView {
        id: scroller
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        Grid{
            // 1) calculate enough columns to fill the width
            columns: Math.floor(scroller.width / 100)  
            // 2) calculate required rows to contain all the elements
            rows: Math.ceil(model.count / columns)  

            Repeater{
                id: model
                model:16
                Rectangle{radius:36;width:100;height:100;color:"blue"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, required a scrollbar. This is great answer, My purpose is simplified by you. Thank you very much.